# How to handle multiple accounts with Android Backup Manager

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I'd like to use the Android Backup Manager in my app to backup data the user has entered. The data is stored as SharedPreferences on the device. The examples I've seen online all look straight forward and easy to follow, but left me with two questions:

1) In my app, the user chooses which Google account on the device to use to connect to my Google App Engine server, and the data they enter is specific to the account they choose. The account they choose could obviously be different than the primary account being used as the "backup account". This becomes a problem if the user has multiple devices, both with the same backup account, but using different accounts for my app. To be clear, I want to handle the case where I have a phone and a tablet both setup to use X@gmail.com as the backup account, and the phone uses X@gmail.com to connect to my server, but the tablet uses Y@gmail.com to connect to my server.

2) How does the Android Backup Service handle multiple backups from different devices using the same backup account? Does the device which backs up last "win", replacing all the previously backed up data? Or if the backup data contains a different set a files, does the Android Backup Service simply add to the backup instead of replacing the data?

My thought to handle issue #1 was to change my app from using a common filename to a filename specific to the user, which could be backed up using the Backup Manager. However, depending on the answer to #2, that may or may not work, because the Backup Service may replace the entire previous backup anyway, even though I'm backing up a different filename.

Any suggestions?